# PyGUI - trying to get scrolling to work in a TextField Object

Tags: python-2.7, pygui

PyGUI: I'm defining a text field to display text from an input source in the usual way:

```
win.status_field = TextField(position = (550, 120), 
    width = 200, text = create_processing_text(),
    multiline = True, lines = 30)
```

This works fine, but when there is too much text I'd like to be able to scroll around or at least word wrap, but I do not see how that is exactly done from interrogating the docs.

Is it just that PyGUI isn't mature enough to do that, and it's time to graduate into PyQT or some other framework? I hate to think of it that way but I don't see any option to accomplish this simple task.

Is there some way to do this which I am overlooking?

Comment: You will have to wrap it manually.  There is [ScrollableView](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python_gui/version/Doc/ScrollableView.html) so maybe you could scroll `TextField`.

Comment: There is [TextEditor](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python_gui/version/Doc/TextEditor.html)  with wrapping and scrolling. Maybe you could use it (with some modifications)

Comment: I tried that as a suitable alternative and was greeted with the following error:

ERROR:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\GUI\WinUtils.py", line 89, in OnCommand
    self._win_menu_command(id)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\GUI\WinUtils.py", line 106, in _win_menu_command
    raise InternalError("_win_menu_command called on non-window: %r" % self)
InternalError: _win_menu_command called on non-window: <GUI.WinUtils.WinMessageReflector object at 0x00000000024CA2E8>

Comment: Here was the code:
CODE:
view = TextEditor(width = 200, height = 200, scrolling = 'hv', anchor = 'ltrb')